# Thymleaf everywhere Spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

hey everyone i have an issue with thymeleaf and my static html pages 
 to be more specific i have a spring mvc web application  am using also spring security , well in my login page i want to use thymeleaf so can spring security communicate with client layer in the other side i don't want to include thymeleaf in my all html pages cause am going to use AngularJs

I tried to put the login in templates folder and the other's in the static folder but id doesn't work

this is my thymleaf configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration 
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean 
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new    ServletContextTemplateResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/vues/");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
resolver.setOrder(1);
return resolver;
}

@Bean 
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
return engine;
}

@Bean 
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
return resolver;
}   

 }
```

my problem is i don't want Thymeleaf included in my all pages you know XHTML is pretty annoying with closing the html tag

any guide will be thankfull

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you dont have to use the XHTML Syntax if u are not including thymleaf into the specific page.